# Increasing JVM heap size without effect - Review of defined options

Tags: java, eclipse, heap-memory, jvm-arguments

*For a large data mining experiment run using Java (Weka), I am trying to assign a larger heap size as said to increase performance.*

I do so by setting the following options in the menu 'Run > Run Configurations > Arguments':

[image]

[The application containing the code to be run indeed is the selected one].

**Two things confuse me:**

- The performance doesn't increase at all. Might still be possible if additional memory doesn't make the program run faster?
- Even if I set values that exceed my machines RAM (4096m) it does not yield any errors. Is that correct or should there be one?

Comment: Why do you think that increasing heap should make the program run faster?

Comment: Can you open activity monitor and see how much memory the actual java process is consuming.  Mac OS X is probably throttling the size to keep everything on your computer running.JVM can't get more memory than Mac OS X will give it

Comment: You should first profile your app's memory and CPU usage using `jvisualvm`.

Comment: @MattBall: That is what usually happens for WEKA experiments, which of cause doesn't assure it has to be the case here. It's rather what I would expect to happen as the models build are hugh.

Comment: I suppose that @Alex might be correct. Checking the CPU and RAM usage, the system is only using part of its resources. I uploaded an example here (machine should actually be running at 100%): http://abload.de/img/bildschirmfoto2013-08gss0c.png Sorry it's in German but the terms should be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

1. Increasing memory will never increase the performance if your program does not need that much memory. So first make sure that your program needs that much memory.
2. Understand the meaning of **xms and xmx**

**xms(initial heap size)** is the initial heap size so system will allocate this much heap for initial use and by specifying **xmx(maximum heap size)** you are telling the system that this is the maximum heap size that you may be using. this is the reason why your system is not yielding any error.

Comment: Thanks for the comment on XMX. Still, I suppose that if neither CPU nor RAM is fully used (see screenshot in my comment above), the computer does not use its full resources. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: you mean you want your system to exploit all the resources ?

Comment: Exactly. Now I got to check the heap-issue using jvisualvm (mentioned above) and it works the it's supposed to. The maximum heap size used was about 2GB and CPU usage at 30%. What's the bottlekneck then? The RAMs speed? Any way to accelerate it any more?